# Exception thrown: read access violation. **dynamicArray** was 0x1118235. occurred

Tags: c++, matrix, dynamic-memory-allocation, access-violation

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int **dynamicArray ;
int ROWS, COLUMNS;

//---------------------------------
int input_matrix(int ROWS, int COLUMNS)
{

    //---------------------------------------
    //memory allocated for elements of rows.
    int **dynamicArray = new int *[ROWS];

    //memory allocated for  elements of each column.
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        dynamicArray[i] = new int [COLUMNS];

    //free the allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        delete[] dynamicArray[i];
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    //-------------------------------------

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            cin >> dynamicArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------
int print_matrix(int **Array)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < COLUMNS; m++)
        {
            cout << Array[k][m];
            if (m == COLUMNS)
            {
                cout << "\n";
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}

//---------------------------------
int main()
{
    cin >> ROWS;
    cin >> COLUMNS;
    input_matrix(ROWS, COLUMNS);
    print_matrix(dynamicArray);

}
```

This code defines a matrix and get inputs and puts them in the members of the matrix but Every time I run this code I get read access violation error on the line:

```
cin >> dynamicArray[i][j];
```

here are the full details:
Exception thrown: read access violation.
**dynamicArray** was 0x1118235. occurred

What should I do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You allocate and then _immediately_ free the array in `input_matrix`. Once you've free'd the array you should not touch/use it. But then at the end of that function you _use_ the array which has been free'd.

Comment: You should free the memory of `dynamicArray` in `main`, after you are done with it.

Comment: You have a bunch of other minor issues: Why not use `vector`? Don't use global variables. `using namespace std` is considered bad. In `print_matrix` `m` will never equal `COLUMNS`.

Comment: The only reason I can come up with why the error is not obvious to you is that you do not realize what "freeing the memory" does -- you even have a comment in your code saying "free the allocated memory".  Yes, you populated the matrix, but that doesn't mean "now I don't need the memory anymore, since the matrix is populated and is now holding my values".  If I'm wrong, so be it, but again, that's the only plausible reason why you would believe that deallocating the memory before actually using the matrix would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your program. Let me list all of them one by one.

1. As mentioned in one of the comments, You are immediately
   deallocating memory just after you allocated it. Definitely this
   will result in a segmentation fault or memory access violation when
   you access deallocated memory.
2. When you allocate the memory you are not
   assigning the allocated memory pointers to global pointer
   `dynamicArray` instead you are creating a local variable with the
   same name inside the function `input_matrix`. As this pointer
   variable scope ends inside the function you are losing the memory
   allocated. Hence again you will face segmentation fault or memory
   access violation inside `print_matrix` function.
3. Inside `print_matrix` function in inner for loop you are checking if `m==COLUMNS` to print new line, this will never happen since m is always less than `COLUMNS`.
4. Finally, as the previous answer suggests when you are using C++, using a vector with smart pointers is a better choice than using array and raw pointers for better memory management.

Following snippet resolves those issues.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int **dynamicArray ;
int ROWS, COLUMNS;

//---------------------------------
int input_matrix(int ROWS, int COLUMNS)
{
    //---------------------------------------
    //memory allocated for elements of rows.
    dynamicArray = new int *[ROWS];

    //memory allocated for  elements of each column.
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        dynamicArray[i] = new int [COLUMNS];

//    cout<<"Input array values\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
        {
            cin>>dynamicArray[i][j];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void free_matrix_memory()
{
    cout<<"freeing allocated memory\n";
    //free the allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
        delete[] dynamicArray[i];
    delete[] dynamicArray;
    //-------------------------------------
}

//---------------------------------------------
int print_matrix(int **Array)
{
    cout<<"printing matrix\n";
    for (int k = 0; k < ROWS; k++)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < COLUMNS; m++)
            cout << Array[k][m];
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

//---------------------------------
int main()
{
    cout<<"Row and column values\n";
    cin>> ROWS;
    cin>> COLUMNS;
    input_matrix(ROWS, COLUMNS);
    print_matrix(dynamicArray);
    free_matrix_memory();
}
```

Still many improvements can be done for your such as avoiding global variables etc., I am leaving it up to you to do those improvements.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are great.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to hand-roll your memory-management in this case. Use `std::vector` (which is a dynamic array) instead or even an actual Matrix library for example 'Eigen'.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Comment: I think it's a perfect answer. OP is even asking 'What should I do?'

Comment: Still a suggestion, since we don't know if he is allowed to use `std::vector` or 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Yes we do, since the question was tagged c++.

Comment: Everybody thanks a lot because of your responses to this question. I don't know  how to use vector instead(also I don't know what is the vector at all :) )

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21288155)

Comment: @TobySpeight It does answer the OPs question - within the same level of detail as the OP has asked his question. SO is not a coding or teaching service - I am giving a full answer that if used will solve the OPs issue 100%. He is even asking broadly: "What should I do ?" Please provide some more detail of why you think this fails to answer the OPs question ?

Comment: I'm sure it's good advice, but it's a bit short as an explanation of what was wrong.  (Actually, the question is better than many - it actually compiles if you remove the local include.  Admittedly, it just blocks waiting for input, but you can't have everything!).  This looks more like a good comment than an answer to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the program under Valgrind, it tells you exactly what's wrong:

```
==6939== Invalid read of size 8
==6939==    at 0x1092C9: input_matrix(int, int) (53083248.cpp:30)
==6939==    by 0x1093FA: main (53083248.cpp:59)
==6939==  Address 0x4d7ecc0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 16 free'd
==6939==    at 0x48373EB: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6939==    by 0x109296: input_matrix(int, int) (53083248.cpp:23)
==6939==    by 0x1093FA: main (53083248.cpp:59)
==6939==  Block was alloc'd at
==6939==    at 0x483654F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6939==    by 0x1091D3: input_matrix(int, int) (53083248.cpp:14)
==6939==    by 0x1093FA: main (53083248.cpp:59)
==6939== 
==6939== Invalid write of size 4
==6939==    at 0x496FFF0: std::istream::operator>>(int&) (istream.tcc:194)
==6939==    by 0x1092EA: input_matrix(int, int) (53083248.cpp:30)
==6939==    by 0x1093FA: main (53083248.cpp:59)
==6939==  Address 0x4d7ed10 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd
==6939==    at 0x48373EB: operator delete[](void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6939==    by 0x10927D: input_matrix(int, int) (53083248.cpp:22)
==6939==    by 0x1093FA: main (53083248.cpp:59)
==6939==  Block was alloc'd at
==6939==    at 0x483654F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6939==    by 0x10922A: input_matrix(int, int) (53083248.cpp:18)
==6939==    by 0x1093FA: main (53083248.cpp:59)
==6939== 
==6939== Invalid read of size 8
==6939==    at 0x10934D: print_matrix(int**) (53083248.cpp:42)
==6939==    by 0x10940C: main (53083248.cpp:60)
==6939==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6939== 
==6939== 
==6939== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6939==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==6939==    at 0x10934D: print_matrix(int**) (53083248.cpp:42)
==6939==    by 0x10940C: main (53083248.cpp:60)
```

There's both read and write to memory that's been freed, and a dereference of `dynamicArray` that was never assigned.

To fix these, you'll need to ensure that your memory lifetimes are appropriate for when you use them, and avoid shadowing `dynamicArray` within `input_matrix()`.

I advise you to avoid raw `new[]` and `delete[]` - prefer to use containers and smart pointers that own resources for you, and automatically release it from their destructors.