# How to correctly fill 2D array in C++ using user input?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a 2D array in C++ and fill it with user input, but once I start typing in values the program just stops giving me "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"

```
double ** array = new double*[col];
for( i=0;i< col; i++){
    array[i] = new double [row];
}


for(i1=0;i1<row;i1++){
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        cin>> n;
        array[i1][j] = n;
    }
}

for(i1=0;i1<row;i1++){
    cout<<" "<<endl;
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        cout<< array[i1][j];
        cout<<" ";

    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: You mixed rows and columns - either in allocation or in usage.

Comment: And please don't use raw pointers and `new[]`, use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Btw. it's not a 2D array - it's an array of pointers to arrays. And a much better replacement is `std::vector` (without the necessity of all these `new`s).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exception thrown: read access violation. \*\*dynamicArray\*\* was 0x1118235. occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083248/exception-thrown-read-access-violation-dynamicarray-was-0x1118235-occurre)

Comment: look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083248/exception-thrown-read-access-violation-dynamicarray-was-0x1118235-occurre/53084215#53084215

Comment: yeah, @Scheff is right, you are mixing rows with colomns in allocation. `double ** array = new double*[row];
for( i=0;i< row; i++){
    array[i] = new double [col];
}`

Comment: If you must use dynamic allocation, create a single dimension array with the total capacity: `array = new double [max_rows * max_columns];` You could then access it as `value = array[row * max_columns + column];`

Answer (score 1):

Let's just ignore memory allocation, for simplicity's sake. Your code should look like this:

```
int val;
  int max = 16;
  int arr[max][max];

  for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
      for(int j = 0; j < max; j++){
        cin >> val;
        arr[j][i] = val;
      }
  }
```

Note how in a 2D array, it goes array[ROW][COLUMN]. Because of this, you want to have a double for loop, with column++ going after a whole for loop of row++. It looks like you've got array[COLUMN][ROW], which is why it's not working properly.